# @ symbol for index keys, when using imakeidx package

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

Using `imakeidx` package, I am generating indices. When defining an index key, I want to use `@` for the key as follows:

```
\index{@variable}
```

`@variable` is the index key. It seems like `@` is deserved for some other usage. How may I use the `@` symbol?

Comment: I believe it is `\index{"@variable}`. You should 'quote' in this way any of: `@`, `!`, and `|` according to the `makeindex` manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@` character is indeed reserved for MakeIndex processing; it is used for entries such as

```
\index{abc@\textit{abc}}
```

where the text to be indexed has formatting and we want to specify a key for sorting purposes.

You have two possibilities. The first is quoting the `@` by typing

```
\index{"@variable}
```

(but this *may* fail if you load `babel` and a language that makes `"` into a shorthand prefix).

The second strategy is adding

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.mst}
actual '='
\end{filecontents*}
```

at the very beginning of your main TeX file (before `\documentclass` is the best place).

This assumes `=` is never used in your entries. The “sort key” entries like the example above can be input using `=` instead of `@`

```
\index{abc=\textit{abc}}
```

and `\index{@variable}` will now be sorted among the symbols.

The trick is that the `filecontents*` environment will write a file named `<jobname>.mst` (where `<jobname>` is the main TeX file name) and MakeIndex looks for it when processing a file.

However, this will prevent loading an `.ist` files, so beware. If you pass no option to MakeIndex, the method will work.